# Html Input into script.sh with PHP excec on Raspberry

Tags: php, shell, input, webserver, raspberry-pi3

I have created a Webserver on my Raspberry. I am able to excecute simple command scripts with PHP, like here:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['on'])) {
exec('sudo /var/www/html/scripts/camOn.sh');
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="on">On</button>
</form>
```

I have following Text to Speech script

```
#!/bin/bash
say() { local IFS=+;/usr/bin/mplayer -ao alsa -really-quiet - noconsolecontrols 
"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&q=$*&tl=En-us"; }
say $*
```

Now I would like to create a Input Text field in Html thats inserts what text I write inside the script, instead of "$*" and executes it after that.

I really have no idea how to do that.
Please help me a little :)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tts'])) {
exec('sudo /var/www/html/scripts/speech.sh');
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
  Text To Speech:<br>
  <input type="text" name="tts"><br>
  Send<br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So in your PHP script you need to do this:

```
exec('sudo /var/www/html/scripts/speech.sh "' . $_POST['tts'] . '"');
```

Then in your bash script the following change:

```
say $1
```

Comment: First argument.

Comment: Is there a way to add a "play" button that outputs the text to speech audio on my website?

Comment: @Jingo you would have to record the audio to a file and then button would play the audio file when clicked. This could be done with javascript and an html5 player pretty easily. Creating the audio might be a challenge.

Comment: Thanks for help, I will look into that. One more thing, when multiple people are on my website and use the text to speech, I can hear it, but the problem is when they submit the text at the same time I hear that at once. Is there a way that the script waits until the audio output is finished, until it starts the new one? I guess that would be pretty complicated? Thanks again

Comment: @Jingo you are using **mplayer** to play the audio. You probably want to create another solution that will record and save the audio and not play it until the user clicks on the button to play the audio.